# Efficient way to filter tf.data based on a string value

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am looking for a solution to efficiently [filter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter) the samples in [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) based on a string value as:
`x = x.filter(lambda data: tf.math.equal(data, value))` though it works but the approach is really slow and if combined with `map` operations it becomes even more slower. Is there any solution that is fast?

Example instance:

```
FeaturesDict({
    'x': DummyObject(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32),
    'y': DummyObject(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64),
    'id': tf.string,
})
```

Comment: Since map() applies a transformation to each element in the dataset and create a new dataset it is expected to be slower, you can increase the performance using 'num_parellel_calls'.

Comment: The focus of the question is not a `map` operation but `filter`. However, already using `num_parallel_calls` and it did not help.